# Groovy script error: Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: writer for class: [the name of my file]

Tags: java, groovy

I keep getting this error while running my groovy script:
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: writer for class: [the name of my file]

However, I don't need a class since it's a groovy script. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a piece of code of your script to better understand the problem.

Comment: You are trying to access `writer` property that was not declared or initialized. Any script actually converted to a class to be compiled.

Comment: Groovy runs in the JVM, which can only run classes. Your Groovy script is converted to a class, then the class' main method containing your script is executed. That's why you see a class in the error message.